# Java blocking on multiple blockers

Tags: java, multithreading, queue, blocking

I'm not a very experienced Java programmer, so forgive me if this is a bit of a newbie question.

I'm designing a system that consists broadly of 3 modules. A client, a server and an application.  The idea is the client sends a message to the server.  The server triggers a use case in the application.  The result of the use case is returned to the server, and the server sends the results to the client.  I opted for this architecture because I'm expecting to need to support multiple clients at once, I want to be able to reuse the server module in other applications, I want to keep the code responsible for managing client connections as uncoupled from the code that implements the domain logic as possible, and because of the opportunity to learn some more advanced java.

I'm planning to tie the various modules together with queues.  The client is simple enough.  Issue a message and block until a response arrives (it may be oversimplifying but it's a reasonable model for now).  The application is equally not a problem.  It blocks on its input queue, executes a use case when it receives a valid message and pushes the results to an output queue.  Having multiple clients makes things a bit more tricky but still within my grasp with my experience level.  The server maintains threads for every open connection, and the server outbound/application inbound queue is synchronised, so if 2 messages arrive at once the second thread will just have to wait a moment for the first thread to deliver its payload into the queue.

The problem is the part in the middle, the server, which will have to block on two independent things.  The server is watching both the client, and the application's output queue (which serves as an input queue for the server).  The server needs to block until either a message comes in from the client (which it then forwards to the application), or until the application completes a task and pushes the results into the application outbound/server inbound queue.

As far as I can tell, Java can only block on one thing.

Is it possible to have the server block until either the client sends a message or the server inbound queue ceases to be empty?

**UPDATE:**

I've had a bit of time to work on this, and have managed to pare the problem down to the bare minimum that illustrates the problem.  There's a somewhat bulky code dump to follow, even with the trimming, so apologies for that.  I'll try to break it up as much as possible.

This is the code for the Server:

```
public class Server implements Runnable {

    private int                     listenPort          = 0;
    private ServerSocket            serverSocket        = null;
    private BlockingQueue<Message>  upstreamMessaes     = null;
    private BlockingQueue<Message>  downstreamMessages  = null;
    private Map<Integer, Session>   sessions            = new ConcurrentHashMap ();
    private AtomicInteger           lastId              = new AtomicInteger ();

    /**
     * Start listening for clients to process
     * 
     * @throws IOException 
     */
    @Override
    public void run () {
        int     newSessionId;
        Session newSession;
        Thread  newThread;

        System.out.println (this.getClass () + " running");

        // Client listen loop
        while (true) {
            newSessionId    = this.lastId.incrementAndGet ();
            try {
                newSession  = new Session (this, newSessionId);
                newThread   = new Thread (newSession);
                newThread.setName ("ServerSession_" + newSessionId);
                this.sessions.put (newSessionId, newSession);
                newThread.start ();
            } catch (IOException ex) {
                Logger.getLogger (Server.class.getName ()).log (Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
            }
        }
    }

    /**
     * Accept a connection from a new client
     * 
     * @return The accepted Socket
     * @throws IOException 
     */
    public Socket accept () throws IOException {
        return this.getSocket().accept ();
    }

    /**
     * Delete the specified Session
     * 
     * @param sessionId ID of the Session to remove
     */
    public void deleteSession (int sessionId) {
        this.sessions.remove (sessionId);
    }

    /**
     * Forward an incoming message from the Client to the application
     * 
     * @param msg
     * @return
     * @throws InterruptedException 
     */
    public Server messageFromClient (Message msg) throws InterruptedException {
        this.upstreamMessaes.put (msg);
        return this;
    }

    /**
     * Set the port to listen to
     * 
     * We can only use ports in the range 1024-65535 (ports below 1024 are 
     * reserved for common protocols such as HTTP and ports above 65535 don't
     * exist)
     * 
     * @param listenPort
     * @return Returns itself so further methods can be called
     * @throws IllegalArgumentException 
     */
    public final Server setListenPort (int listenPort) throws IllegalArgumentException {
        if ((listenPort > 1023) && (listenPort <= 65535)) {
            this.listenPort = listenPort;
        } else {
            throw new IllegalArgumentException ("Port number " + listenPort + " not valid");
        }

        return this;
    }

    /**
     * Get the server socket, initialize it if it isn't already started.
     * 
     * @return The object's ServerSocket
     * @throws IOException 
     */
    private ServerSocket getSocket () throws IOException {
        if (null == this.serverSocket) {
            this.serverSocket = new ServerSocket (this.listenPort);
        }

        return this.serverSocket;
    }

    /**
     * Instantiate the server
     * 
     * @param listenPort
     * @throws IllegalArgumentException 
     */
    public Server ( int listenPort, 
                    BlockingQueue<Message> incomingMessages, 
                    BlockingQueue<Message> outgoingMessages) throws IllegalArgumentException {
        this.setListenPort (listenPort);
        this.upstreamMessaes    = incomingMessages;
        this.downstreamMessages = outgoingMessages;
        System.out.println (this.getClass () + " created");
        System.out.println ("Listening on port " + listenPort);
    }
}
```

I believe the following method belongs in the Server but is currently commented out.

```
    /**
     * Notify a Session of a message for it
     * 
     * @param sessionMessage 
     */
    public void notifySession () throws InterruptedException, IOException {
        Message sessionMessage  = this.downstreamMessages.take ();
        Session targetSession   = this.sessions.get (sessionMessage.getClientID ());
        targetSession.waitForServer (sessionMessage);
    }
```

This is my Session class

```
public class Session implements Runnable {
    private Socket              clientSocket    = null;
    private OutputStreamWriter  streamWriter    = null;
    private StringBuffer        outputBuffer    = null;
    private Server              server          = null;
    private int                 sessionId       = 0;

    /**
     * Session main loop
     */
    @Override
    public void run () {

        StringBuffer    inputBuffer = new StringBuffer ();
        BufferedReader  inReader;

        try {
            // Connect message
            this.sendMessageToClient ("Hello, you are client " + this.getId ());
            inReader    = new BufferedReader (new InputStreamReader (this.clientSocket.getInputStream (), "UTF8"));

            do {
                // Parse whatever was in the input buffer
                inputBuffer.delete (0, inputBuffer.length ());
                inputBuffer.append (inReader.readLine ());
                System.out.println ("Input message was: " + inputBuffer);
                this.server.messageFromClient (new Message (this.sessionId, inputBuffer.toString ()));
            } while (!"QUIT".equals (inputBuffer.toString ()));

            // Disconnect message
            this.sendMessageToClient ("Goodbye, client " + this.getId ());
        } catch (IOException | InterruptedException e) {
            Logger.getLogger (Session.class.getName ()).log (Level.SEVERE, null, e);
        } finally {
            this.terminate ();
            this.server.deleteSession (this.getId ());
        }
    }

    /**
     * 
     * @param msg
     * @return
     * @throws IOException 
     */
    public Session waitForServer (Message msg) throws IOException {
        // Generate a response for the input
        String output   = this.buildResponse (msg.getPayload ()).toString ();
        System.out.println ("Output message will be: " + output);

        // Output to client
        this.sendMessageToClient (output);

        return this;
    }

    /**
     * 
     * @param request
     * @return 
     */
    private StringBuffer buildResponse (CharSequence request) {
        StringBuffer ob = this.outputBuffer;
        ob.delete (0, this.outputBuffer.length ());

        ob.append ("Server repsonded at ")
          .append (new java.util.Date ().toString () )
          .append (" (You said '" )
          .append (request)
          .append ("')");

        return this.outputBuffer;
    }

    /**
     * Send the given message to the client
     * 
     * @param message
     * @throws IOException 
     */
    private void sendMessageToClient (CharSequence message) throws IOException {
        // Output to client
        OutputStreamWriter osw  = this.getStreamWriter ();
        osw.write ((String) message);
        osw.write ("\r\n");
        osw.flush ();
    }

    /**
     * Get an output stream writer, initialize it if it's not active
     * 
     * @return A configured OutputStreamWriter object
     * @throws IOException 
     */
    private OutputStreamWriter getStreamWriter () throws IOException {
        if (null == this.streamWriter) {
            BufferedOutputStream os = new BufferedOutputStream (this.clientSocket.getOutputStream ());
            this.streamWriter       = new OutputStreamWriter (os, "UTF8");
        }

        return this.streamWriter;
    }

    /**
     * Terminate the client connection
     */
    private void terminate () {
        try {
            this.streamWriter   = null;
            this.clientSocket.close ();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            Logger.getLogger (Session.class.getName ()).log (Level.SEVERE, null, e);
        }
    }

    /**
     * Get this Session's ID
     * 
     * @return The ID of this session
     */
    public int getId () {
        return this.sessionId;
    }

    /**
     * Session constructor
     * 
     * @param owner The Server object that owns this session
     * @param sessionId The unique ID this session will be given
     * @throws IOException 
     */
    public Session (Server owner, int sessionId) throws IOException {
        System.out.println ("Class " + this.getClass () + " created");

        this.server         = owner;
        this.sessionId      = sessionId;
        this.clientSocket   = this.server.accept ();

        System.out.println ("Session ID is " + this.sessionId);
    }
}
```

The test application is fairly basic, it just echoes a modified version of the original request message back.  The real application will do work on receipt of a message and returning a meaningful response to the Server.

```
public class TestApp implements Runnable {
    private BlockingQueue <Message> inputMessages, outputMessages;

    @Override
    public void run () {
        Message         lastMessage;
        StringBuilder   returnMessage   = new StringBuilder ();

        while (true) {
            try {
                lastMessage = this.inputMessages.take ();

                // Construct a response
                returnMessage.delete (0, returnMessage.length ());
                returnMessage.append ("Server repsonded at ")
                             .append (new java.util.Date ().toString () )
                             .append (" (You said '" )
                             .append (lastMessage.getPayload ())
                             .append ("')");

                // Pretend we're doing some work that takes a while
                Thread.sleep (1000);

                this.outputMessages.put (new Message (lastMessage.getClientID (), lastMessage.toString ()));
            } catch (InterruptedException ex) {
                Logger.getLogger (TestApp.class.getName ()).log (Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
            }
        }
    }

    /**
     * Initialize the application
     * 
     * @param inputMessages Where input messages come from
     * @param outputMessages Where output messages go to
     */
    public TestApp (BlockingQueue<Message> inputMessages, BlockingQueue<Message> outputMessages) {
        this.inputMessages = inputMessages;
        this.outputMessages = outputMessages;
        System.out.println (this.getClass () + " created");
    }
}
```

The Message class is extremely simple and just consists of an originating client ID and a payload string, so I've left it out.

Finally the main class looks like this.

```
public class Runner {
    /**
     * 
     * @param args The first argument is the port to listen on.
     * @throws Exception  
     */
    public static void main (String[] args) throws Exception {
        BlockingQueue<Message>  clientBuffer    = new LinkedBlockingQueue (); 
        BlockingQueue<Message>  appBuffer       = new LinkedBlockingQueue ();
        TestApp appInstance                     = new TestApp (clientBuffer, appBuffer);
        Server serverInstance                   = new Server (Integer.parseInt (args [0]), clientBuffer, appBuffer);
        Thread appThread                        = new Thread (appInstance);
        Thread serverThread                     = new Thread (serverInstance);

        appThread.setName("Application");
        serverThread.setName ("Server");

        appThread.start ();
        serverThread.start ();

        appThread.join ();
        serverThread.join ();

        System.exit (0);
    }
}
```

While the real application will be more complex the TestApp illustrates the basic pattern of use.  It blocks on its input queue until there's something there, processes it, then pushes the result onto its output queue.

Session classes manage a live connection between a particular client and the server.  It takes input from the client and converts it to Message objects, and it takes Message objects from the Server and converts them to output to send to the client.

The Server listens for new incoming connections and sets up a Session object for each incoming connection it has.  When a Session passes it a Message, it puts it into its upstream queue for the application to deal with.

The difficulty I'm having is getting return messages to travel back down from the TestApp to the various clients.  When a message from a client comes in, the Session generates a Message and sends it to the Server, which then puts it into its upstream queue, which is also the input queue for the TestApp.  In response, the TestApp generates a response Message and puts it into the output queue, which is also the downstream queue for the Server.

This means that Sessions need to wait for two unrelated events.  They should block until

- Input arrives from the client (the BufferedReader on the client socket has input to process),
- OR a message is sent to it by the Server (the server calls the WaitForServer () method on the session)

As for the Server itself, it also has to wait for two unrelated events.

- a Session calls messageFromClient() with a message to pass to the TestApp,
- OR the TestApp pushes a message onto the output/downstream queue to be passed onto a Session.

What on the face of it looked like a simple task to achieve is proving a lot more difficult than I first imagined.  I expect I'm overlooking something obvious, as I'm still quite new to concurrent programming, but if you can help point out where I'm going wrong I'd appreciate instruction.

Comment: It seems like the easiest solution is to assign one thread per blocking item, e.g. rather than have the server consist of one thread managing two queues it would instead consist of two threads, one per queue (which can then block independently of each other).  A somewhat messier alternative is to merge the two server queues, and have all incoming messages contain routing information (probably just an enum value, SESSION or APP) so that the server knows where to send them - this way the server only has to wait on a single queue.  Is either of these an option for you?

Comment: I am considering the 2 threads idea, but I think that would mean 2 threads per session.  It'd be very easy for the number of threads to balloon out of control if I'm not careful.  The other approach is attractive, but I'm not sure how to go about doing it, because one source of events is a blocking queue from the application, while the other is a socket from the client.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because your implementation is using methods to pass data between client-session-server, you've actually already solved your immediate problem.  However, this may not have been your intention.  Here's what's happening:

Session's `run` method is running in its own thread, blocking on the socket.  When the server calls `waitForServer`, this method immediately executes **in the server's thread** - in Java, if a thread calls a method then that method executes in that thread, and so in this case the Session did not need to unblock.  In order to create the problem you are trying to solve, you would need to remove the `waitForServer` method and replace it with a `BlockingQueue messagesFromServer` queue - then the Server would place messages in this queue and Session would would need to block on it, resulting in Session needing to block on two different objects (the socket and the queue).

Assuming that you switch to the implementation where the Session will need to block on two objects, I think you can solve this with a hybrid of the two approaches I described in the comments:

Each Session's socket will need a thread to block on it - I don't see any way around this, unless you're willing to replace this with a fixed thread pool (say, 4 threads) that poll the sockets and sleep for a few dozen milliseconds if there's nothing to read from them.

You can manage all Server -> Sessions traffic with a single queue and a single thread that blocks on it - the Server includes the Session "address" in its payload so that the thread blocking on it knows what to do with the message.  If you find that this doesn't scale when you have a lot of sessions, then you can always increase the thread/queue count, e.g. with 32 sessions you can have 4 threads/queues, 8 sessions per thread/queue.

Comment: Okay, thanks for the reply. Am working through it and trying to figure your idea out, though this is pretty advanced stuff from my level of experience.  I guess scaling won't really be a concern as this is an academic project.  If I understand right, the Server should have a single incoming queue, that both the Application and the Sessions can push messages onto, and that depending on some distinguishing feature of the Message (flag, subclass, etc), the Server routes the Message to either the appropriate Session or the Application. Is this correct?

Comment: That's correct - if you only have a single Session and Application then all you need is an Enum{SESSION, APP} with an if-else in the Server to route the messages (alternatively you could use an `instanceof` instead of an enum, the bottom line though is that you just need an if-else for routing), whereas if you had multiple Sessions/Applications then the sessions/apps would need unique Ids and server would need a `HashMap<String, Destination>` to route messages

Comment: Well the plan is to have a single Application, and a collection of Sessions for each open connection (The Server serves as a front end for the Application but there's no requirement for them to run on separate machines).  I guess there's no reason why the Application and the Sessions push incoming Messages to the Server in the same way if there's a simple way to tell which way a Message is going.

Comment: I think this is going to take more work, but I think I can get this working with the following.  The App is a single thread that just waits for input, processes it and returns output.  The Server consists of 3 threads, upstream thread takes input from sessions and sends it to app, downstream thread takes input from app and sends it to the right session, listener thread establishes new connections.  Sessions also consist of an upstream and downstream thread which encode and decode raw stream data into message objects to send over the wire.

Comment: That looks reasonable.  You can merge the upstream/downstream queues/threads if you want, but that's not really necessary at this point - you don't have an excess of threads, it's just something to keep in mind for future development.  Something else to keep in mind for the future is that you can use a [ThreadPoolExecutor](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ThreadPoolExecutor.html) to launch runnables rather than using `new Thread` - this reuses threads rather than constructing new ones out of whole cloth.

Comment: In your case your threads exist for the lifetime of your program, so there's no benefit (that I'm aware of) to using an ExecutorService.

Comment: Yeah, after posting this I realised that message routing in the server would be simple enough to only require a single thread.  The Session threads only last for the duration of an open connection so the Thread Pool might be something to bear in mind there (though I'll probably not actually try it because there's more than enough to worry about already :) )

Answer (score 0):

I may have misunderstood but it seems that where you have the code "listening" for a message, you should be able to use a simple OR statement to solve this.

One other thing that might be useful is to add a unique id to every client so you can tell which client the message is intended for.

Comment: Yeah, I do think you misunderstood. :)  The clients already get a unique ID.  This isn't also a problem that can be solved with just a simple or, as it's time dependant.  The main server thread has to wait until either one or the other condition is true.  However you can't just sit in a loop as it would just peg the thread CPU usage at 100% for basically doing nothing.